# How to get vertices of Fixture in andengine/box2d

Tags: box2d, andengine

Hi I need to get all vertices of fixture I have created so I've done this

```
PolygonShape cs = (PolygonShape) rubeDef.getFixtureByName("fixture0").getShape();
Vector2[] testVertex = new Vector2[cs.getVertexCount()];
```

but now I can't access each individual vertex to fill my array. There is an method to get each vertex - cs.getVertex(index, vertex);, but I don't see how this gets the vertex?? the method is void and it requires a vertex as param, why would you need that param for a getter method. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the source should clear this up:

```
public void getVertex (int index, Vector2 vertex) {
    jniGetVertex(addr, index, verts);
    vertex.x = verts[0];
    vertex.y = verts[1];
}
```

The idea is that the vector passed as the parameter will be set with the values upon return.